# GeoTools: java.util.{List, Map} in SimpleFeature

Tags: java, geotools

I'd like to add a List(Map) as Attribute to a SimpleFeature when using the PostGIS datastore:

```
SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder simpleFeatureTypeBuilder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
simpleFeatureTypeBuilder.add("list", List.class);
```

this causes:

```
Dec 05, 2019 8:48:51 AM org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource buildFeatureType
WARNING: Could not find mapping for 'list', ignoring the column and setting the feature type read only
```

Therefore my question is how to I register the mapping properly?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you can't do that. The PostGIS datastore has no idea how to map a `List` back into a PostgreSQL or PostGIS type so it ignores the attribute.

Since [GeoTools 19.0](https://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2018/03/geotools-190-released.html) there has been support for reading `hstore` attributes back as a `Map`, but without trying it I don't know if there is support for writing them. The best thing to try would be creating a table with an `hstore` column and getting it's `FeatureType` to see if it contains a map.

Comment: `hstore` support seems to be limited to reading, at least in geotools version 20.5. When trying to write something I get the same Warning.

Comment: PR would be welcome then